# Create a dynamic list of vmware datastore using Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a list of vmware datastores using Ansible playbook and later use it to create a VM . I'm new to Ansible playbook. Appreciate any help!

I'm getting the info using vmware_datastore_info as shown below.

```yaml
    "info.datastores": [
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 4397778075648,
            "datastore_cluster": "N/A",
            "freeSpace": 4192023347200,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "DDA-san010-L10",
            "provisioned": 219122982172,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 13368253724,
           
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 4397778075648,
            "datastore_cluster": "N/A",
            "freeSpace": 4134386270208,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "DDA-san011-L11",
            "provisioned": 279761501112,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 16369695672,
            
        },
        {

         .......................
        }
```

now I need to capture the above info in a list of dictionary items so that I can use the name of the datastore using the freespace to allocate the datastore for a new vm.

the playbook that I'm using to gather the info is give below

```yaml
--- 
- name: Gather info from standalone ESXi server having datacenter as 'LAB'
  hosts: localhost 
  gather_facts: false 
  vars_files: 
    - /data/password.yml 
    - /data/windows/lab_vars.yml 
  tasks: 
  - name: Collect info regarding datastore 
    vmware_datastore_info: 
      hostname: '{{ vcenter_server }}' 
      username: '{{ username }}' 
      password: '{{ password }}' 
      datacenter_name: '{{ datacenter_name }}' 
      validate_certs: false 
    delegate_to: localhost 
    register: info 

  - debug: var=info.datastores
```

Comment: don't forget share your playbook.

Comment: ---
- name: Gather info from standalone ESXi server having datacenter as 'LAB'
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars_files:
    - /data/password.yml
    - /data/windows/lab_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Collect info regarding datastore
      vmware_datastore_info:
        hostname: '{{ vcenter_server }}'
        username: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        datacenter_name: '{{ datacenter_name }}'
        validate_certs: false
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: info
- debug: var=info.datastores

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. Below is the additional code.

set_fact:
datastore: "{{ datastore + [{ 'Name': item.name, 'Cluster': item.datastore_cluster,  'Capacity': item.capacity, 'Freespace': item.freeSpace, 'Provisioned': item.provisioned , 'Accessible': item.accessible }] }}"
with_items:
- "{{ info.datastores }}"

Now the next step is to find the datastore that has the least amount of space to fit the server.